# How do I set up a virtual environment in pycharm which runs python (and pipenv) 2.7 when I already have python 3.6 installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pycharm, pipenv

I want to run a Python 2.7 program in Pycharm. I have installed Python 3.6 prior to that and have now installed Python 2.7.

Now I am able to set up a virtual environment using python 2.7 in Pycharm but I am unable to install any packages.

I added the Variables

> ..\Python36;  
>   ..\Python36\Scripts; 
>   ..\Python36\Lib\site-packages,
>   ..\Python36\DLLs;

and

> ..\Python27;
>   ..\Python27\Scripts;
>   ..\Python27\Lib\site-packages;
>   ..\Python27\DLLs;

to the SYSTEM PATH environment variables.

I also tried renaming the python executables. With this I can run the command python2 in cmd but when I try to install a package through cmd with the command "python2 -m pip install pipenv" I get the error:

>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)<br>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals<br>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module><br>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "C:\Users\JO013U\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 19, in <module><br>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module><br>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 7, in <module><br>
    from socket import error as SocketError, timeout as SocketTimeout
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module><br>
    import _socket<br>
ImportError: Module use of python36.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

I get a similar error connected to python36.dll conflicts when trying to do the same in pycharm.

I am not sure what I am missing here and would be really grateful, if someone could help me out and point me to my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add any variables manually nor rename any executables. Try to install the packages through command line, but make sure that virtual environment is **active**. When it's active, you'll see its name in the brackets at the beginning of each line.

In PyCharm, when you open the embedded Terminal, virtual environment is activated by default but when you want to interact with it outside of PyCharm, you need to activate it manually. Activating virtual environment is documented [here](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/#activate-script). Under Windows you'll need to use the activation script which is located in `\path\to\env\Scripts\activate`.

When the environment is active, installing packages should be possible by typing:

```
python -m pip install thePackageYouNeed
```

`python` in this case will point to the interpreter which was used for creating the environment.